# Centering the react component doesn't work

Tags: css, reactjs

**LoginComponent.js**

```
  render() {
    return (
       <div className="col-md-6">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
            <input value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleChange} type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email" />
            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
          </div>
        </form>

      </div>
    );
  }
```

This is how my LoginComponent, which is just a login box component renders like above. I wanted to center align this.

**Login.js**

```
const loginStyles = {
  display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center'
}

class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <LoginComponent style={loginStyles}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

So, I simple used flex and justifiyContent to make the box go to center of the page, but it keeps staying on the top-left of the page. How can I handle this issue?

Comment: `<div style={loginStyles}>`

Answer (score 0):

Besides the other answer, you need also set the width of the parent `div` component for horizontal centering. So in your case you can set parent `div` width to `width: "100%"'

```
const loginStyles = {
  display: 'flex', 
  justifyContent: 'center', 
  width: "100%"
}
```

Comment: as a block element, a `div` has 100% width by default, so no need to add it.

Comment: this only centers it horizontally, how can I also make it center vertically?

Answer (score 0):

This is because passing `style={loginStyles}` to your `LoginComponent` does nothing, if you don't use that prop...

`style` must be set on an HTML tag. You could try wrapping your whole JSX with another div, as such:

```
render() {
    return (
       <div style={this.props.style}>
        <div className="col-md-6">
          <form>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
              <input value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleChange} type="email" name="email" className="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email" />
              <small id="emailHelp" className="form-text text-muted">We&apos;ll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
            </div>
          </form>

        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

That way your `LoginComponent` will actually use the `style` prop passed by its parent.